# What are the yellow-background items in Ivy?

Tags: faces, minibuffer, ivy

I'm currently migrating from Helm to ivy+counsel, and I have a problem with the faces ivy applies in the minibuffer for some commands. See this example:

[image: An ivy completion of describe-function]

Some of the possible selections are highlighted with a yellow background. However, the face for the currently selected item has a yellow foreground, so it can't be read against that background.

I could of course just switch the foreground of the selected item (via the face `ivy-current-match`) to have a blue foreground or whatever, but I would also like to know what the difference between the items highlighted via yellow background and the non-highlighted ones is, and what face is used to do that highlighting.

Since all of this happens in a minibuffer, I can't just hit `C-u C-x =` to get the faces at point (or rather: I can, but I can't move the point to one of these items). Is there a way to see the faces active in the minibuffer?

This does not happen for all selections via ivy. `find-file`, `switch-to-buffer` and `execute-extended-command` seem unaffected (i.e., don't have background-highlighted items), but the help commands (`C-h k`, `C-h v`, `C-h f` etc.) are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `ivy-highlight-face`. According to the [source code](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/6a22192f11a4aa0d43692bf685fd9b9d75911d00/counsel.el#L556-L580):

> "Forward to `describe-function'.
>
> Interactive functions (i.e., commands) are highlighted according
> to `ivy-highlight-face'."